# PHP MYSQL connecting to Session for Username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, session

So I have the following code:

```
 <?php

          try {
// Show existing entries.
foreach($db->query('SELECT * from register') as $row)  {
        echo "<strong>" . $row['firstName'] ."</strong> " . "<strong>" .   $row['surname'] ."</strong> "
        . " Course = " . $row['course'] . 
        " Subject = " . $row['subject'] . " Level = " . $row['level'] . " Date = " . $row['date'] . " Time = " . $row['time'] .
        "</div>";
   }
 } catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "An error occurred in reading or writing to register.";
}
$db = null;
?>
```

All of the code works fine and I can view all of the entries for the database table 'register'. But I want to only view one user, the user who is logged in which is saved as a session. I have tried entering in a WHERE clause like:

```
  foreach($db->query('SELECT * from register WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."'') as $row)
```

I have tried various techniques but the end result has either been: no results are shown or come up on the page. Or there is a syntax error.

So what is the correct syntax or way to only select the user that is logged in via session?

I am using a Google App Engine PHP website and Cloud MySQL database attached.
So basically, the user logs in and the username is 'username'. So the session has the username = 'username', how would I only select the user that is currently logged in. So the username would be different for each user so I am trying to get the username from the session for the WHERE clause.

Comment: look closely, the highlighter already gives the hint `'". $_SESSION['username']."''` and why not bind those

Comment: So how would it look binded?

Comment: i'd suggest follow this way instead http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Named_Placeholders

Comment: Thank you. But I don't get how to use the session with the WHERE clause, because if I have the normal WHERE username = username then it will only select one. But there are many accounts so I only want to select the session username

Comment: what do you mean it will only select one? ofcourse it will only select one, unless you intend you want duplicate usernames which is weird.

Comment: No I mean if I have the query as WHERE username = Tom. Then it will only display Tom every time, but the details will be different for each user and I cant have a query for each user, so just a query that gets the username from the session rather than stating the username

Comment: use the answer below, it'll only show the currently logged on user, your currently code's problem is only on the quotation and concatenation on the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$s="SELECT * from register WHERE username = '". $_SESSION['username']."'";
```

you may store your query in another local variable and execute it.